# Is Groovy 3.0.5 incompatible with Mockito 3.6.28 ? Mocks are not usable

Tags: java, groovy, mocking, mockito

I am currently trying to move from `Junit 4` `Mockito 3.2.4` in order (mainly), to benefit from `mockStatic` and get rid of `PowerMock`

Migration went surprisingly well until I arrived at the test mocking static methods. `Groovy 2.4.6`, which is currently in used, does not support method reference operator `::`

I am now trying to migrate to Groovy 3.0.5 and I have an issue opening mocks. Here is a simple code that reflect the issue:

```
class Article {
    Article() {
    }

    String getName() {
        return "toto"
    }

}


class ArticleManager {

    private Article article
    ArticleManager(Article article) {
        this.article = article
    }

    static int getArticleCount() {
        return 5
    }

    Article getArticleAt(int index) {
        return article
    }

}

import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.mockito.Mock
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations

import static org.mockito.Mockito.any
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when

class MockTest {

    private AutoCloseable closeable
    Article article

    @Mock
    private ArticleManager manager


    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        article = new Article()
        closeable = MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this)
    }

    @AfterEach
    void releaseMocks() throws Exception {
        closeable.close()
    }

    @Test
    void testGroovy() {

        assert article.getName() == "toto"

        assert manager != null

        assert manager.getArticleAt(0) == null
        when(manager.getArticleAt(any(Integer.class))).thenReturn(article)
        assert manager.getArticleAt(0) == article
    }
}
```

- Running this test with groovy 2.4.6 => **OK**
- Running this test with a Java equivalent of code (no groovy) => **OK**
- Running this test with groovy 3.0.5 =>

  - `manager.getArticleAt(0) - > java.lang.NullPointerException`
  - `when(manager.getArticleAt(any(Integer.class))).thenReturn(article)` -> Method threw 'org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException' exception.
  - manager is not null, it's an `ArticleManager$MockitoMocks$`

I am doing something wrong here or is there an incompatibility of some sort ?

Thank you very much

Comment: In older groovy versions you can often use `.&` instead of `::`

Comment: That seems to work but now I have the following error: The used `MockMaker SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker does not support the creation of static mocks Mockito's inline mock maker supports static mocks based on the Instrumentation API.`
I googled it and it seems I should use mockito-inline instead of mockito-core. But when I do that, I have the exact same problem that described in my original post

Comment: I think the NPE is the age old metaclass problem. You can try when(manager.getMetaClass()).thenCallRealMethod() or add "answer=Answers.CALL_REAL_METHOD" to the mock annotation. There once was a compatibility mockito plugin that fixed this under the hood.

Comment: As for the matcher, I think anyInt() is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you I will investigate this as soon as Monday. But why would I want my mock to call the real method ? I do that only on a case to case basis

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same thing in my project. I think it's indeed the "age old metaclass problem", aka [mockito/mockito#72](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/72), and I think it's occurring again with Groovy 3.0 because [the internal methods are no longer marked synthetic](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-8495). I have reported [mockito/mockito#2204](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/2204) about this.

**EDIT 2021-02-15:** I submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/pull/2207) to fix this. It has been [accepted](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/commit/84774556217c23472e54ff9ffe32bc041a40426d) and [released](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/releases/tag/v3.7.18), so please try again with Mockito v3.7.18.

Comment: so from what you are saying it's a bug that should be fixed ?

Comment: Yes, and in fact my pull request to fix it was accepted and released this morning. So please try your tests with Mockito v3.7.18. https://github.com/mockito/mockito/releases/tag/v3.7.18