# Mockito incorrect argument matcher after Jenkins core upgrade

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, mockito, matcher

We have Jenkins shared library project with some unit-tests that utilize Mockito.
After an upgrade of Jenkins-core from version 2.325 to 2.326 tests start failing on the following line:

```
class DSLMock {

  DSLMock() {

    this.mock = mock(DSL.class)

->  when(mock.invokeMethod(eq("error"), any())).then(new Answer<String>() {
      @Override
      String answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {
        throw new AbortException((String) invocationOnMock.getArguments()[1][0])
      }
    })
...
```

with error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected here:
-> at com.devops.jenkins.testing.DSLMock.<init>(DSLMock.groovy:66)
-> at com.devops.jenkins.testing.DSLMock.<init>(DSLMock.groovy:66)
You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
    when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
    verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))
This message may appear after an NullPointerException if the last matcher is returning an object 
like any() but the stubbed method signature expect a primitive argument, in this case,
use primitive alternatives.
    when(mock.get(any())); // bad use, will raise NPE
    when(mock.get(anyInt())); // correct usage use
Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with methods that cannot be mocked.
Following methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode().
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
```

I've tried to replace any() with methods like anyString() and just value like "" but still got same error.
Also I've tried different stub syntax like

```
doAnswer(new Answer...).when(mock).invokeMethod(eq("error"), any())
```

In changelog https://www.jenkins.io/changelog-old/#v2.326 I see Groovy patch version has been upgraded:

- Upgrade Groovy from 2.4.12 to 2.4.21

I wonder if that would cause the issue. Other dependencies versions are not changed:

```
<groovy.version>2.4.12</groovy.version>
<junit-jupiter.version>5.8.1</junit-jupiter.version>
<mockito.core.version>3.3.3</mockito.core.version>
```

Comment: What class are you trying to mock?

Comment: DSL class from org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps

Comment: »Following methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified: final/private/[…]. Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.« Any of those apply?

Comment: I guess it doesn't apply https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-cps/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/cps/DSL.html#invokeMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-

Comment: and it had worked fine before until the upgrade of the dependency

Comment: The answer is probably to be found somewhere in [here](https://github.com/apache/groovy/compare/GROOVY_2_4_12...GROOVY_2_4_21).

Comment: @KnightIndustries thank you for the comment. I've checked the changelog and the only thing I've found related to mocks is subprojects/groovy-test/src/main/java/groovy/mock/interceptor/MockProxyMetaClass.java

Comment: What happens when you use `any(TheArgument.class)` instead of plain `any()`?

Comment: @Lino same error

Comment: Hey @kirill-a , can you please check my latest comment on my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there have been similar issues with other versions of Groovy and Mockito: [Is Groovy 3.0.5 incompatible with Mockito 3.6.28 ? Mocks are not usable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65329154/is-groovy-3-0-5-incompatible-with-mockito-3-6-28-mocks-are-not-usable)

However, even the latest version of Mockito doesn't seem to fix the issue with the version of Groovy that you're using. In the meantime, this worked for me:

```
@Test
void shouldMockObject() {
    DSL mock = spy(new DSL(null) {
        @Override
        Object invokeMethod(String name, Object args) {
            return null
        }
    })

    when(mock.invokeMethod(eq("error"), any())).then(new Answer<String>() {
        @Override
        String answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {
            throw new AbortException((String) invocationOnMock.getArguments()[1][0])
        }
    })

    assertThrows(AbortException.class) {
        mock.invokeMethod("error", [ "message" ])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your error locally but faced a compilation error on line: `throw new AbortException((String) invocationOnMock.getArguments()[1][0])`. Could you maybe try the following:

```java
when(mock.invokeMethod(eq("error"), any(String[].class))).then(new Answer<String>() {
    @Override
    public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {
        String[] array = (String[]) invocationOnMock.getArguments()[1];
        throw new AbortException((String) array[0]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Both variants compile for me, but during test run this throws the same error as in question on line when(mock...

Comment: How are you calling the invokeMethod? Are you sure there is an array of values as the second param? Are you sure that that array has an element at index 0? Because it could easily be because of getting a NPE (as you might read in the description of the error)...

Comment: InvokeMethod has 2 parameters invokeMethod​(String name, Object args)
I invoke it using String matcher and any() that should work for any object. If you're talking about return value, I can change it to anything just return true and get same error on matches (first line)

Comment: What I mean is how are you calling the method after mocking it...in the following part of the test code or inside your application code. Is the Object args a vararg param? Or is it merely a single object reference? Because if it is just a simple Object, **you will** get a NPE because you are doing `invocationOnMock.getArguments()[1][0]` which is, you are accessing the second parameter with [1] and then doing [0] will get you a NPE because you can only do that in arrays and Object args is not an array.

Comment: @mrkachariker it looks like you're writing Java code. From my investigations, the problem appears only when the mocking is done in a Groovy class.

Answer (score 0):

The `doAnswer(...).when(mock).call(...)` doesn't trigger much if any execution within the mock.  Also static compilation can shut down Groovy's dynamic behavior, which can help since you're overriding `invokeMethod(String,Object)` which has special significance.

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*
// ...
class DSLMock {
  @groovy.transform.CompileStatic
  DSLMock() {
    this.mock = mock(DSL)
    doCallRealMethod().when(this.mock).getMetaClass() // if DSL implements GroovyObject
    doAnswer({ iom ->
      throw new AbortException(iom.getArgumentAt(1, String[])[0])
    }).when(this.mock).invokeMethod(eq('error'), anyObject())
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: CompileStatic threw me a bunch of errors
`Cannot find matching method`
`throw new AbortException(iom.getArgumentAt(1, String[])[0])`
`Cannot find matching method hudson.AbortException#<init>(java.lang.Object)`
`throw new AbortException(iom.getArgumentAt(1, String[])[0])`
`Cannot statically compile constructor implicitly including non static elements from object`

Comment: Without it, the line doCallRealMethod... error:
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at com.devops.jenkins.testing.DSLMock.<init>(DSLMock.groovy:88)
E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, which is not supported
 3. you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction is completed